# Rails Webpacker: expire all assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, sprockets, webpacker

Does anyone know if there is a way to update all fingerprints generated by Rails Webpacker?

I have a pack tag called `manifest.js` that is auto-generated so I can't change the contents but some browsers have cached a bad response due to some CORS issues and now I want to change the fingerprint to something else to flush the cache.

I notice in the old Rails assets pipeline there was an option in the assets initializer called `Rails.application.config.assets.version` but changing this value doesn't seem to affect Webpacker fingerprints.

Thanks!